# How to encrypt pdf files securely

Tags: spring-boot, security, pdf, encryption

I have an application, where spring-boot is back-end and jquery is front-end. I can create document but without encryption or any kind of protection, so i need to figure it out.

I need to secure pdf files. What is the best way to do that?

- I could add option to set passwords for that pdf file on the front-end side. So user who has permission to create documents would set password for him and for users who can access the document.
- The same story, but creator of document would only choose password for normal users and the "main" password would be secretely used only on the back-end side
- How would I store those passwords? In database? And how/which format?
- How would I distribute those passwords to users? Is it safe to use email for sending this password to users? But again, the password must be somewhere securely stored.
- Is it a good approach? Or what would be the best to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your concerns can be easiely handled by the [IText Engine](https://itextpdf.com/en).

This toolkit comes with handy features for PDF Generation and Manipulation( including secure PDF with password and other signature encryption systems).

Here is a basic [example](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/faq/technical-support/itext-7/how-protect-already-existing-pdf-password) :

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
WriterProperties props = new WriterProperties()
        .setStandardEncryption(USERPASS, OWNERPASS, EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
                EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128 | EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA);
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(dest), props);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
pdfDoc.close();
```

**NOTE :**

Note that **USERPASS** and **OWNERPASS** are of type `byte[]`

```
public static byte[] USERPASS = "superuser".getBytes(); public static byte[] OWNERPASS = "superowner".getBytes();
```

You have different options for the permissions (look for `EncryprionConstants` starting with ALLOW_) and also you can chose from different encryption algorithms.

Comment: yes thank you, I will check it out. But eventhough I would use this, It does not answer my question. How to do it securely? Storing passwords etc...

Comment: And how would you send password to users who can access the document? Email is not secure i guess... And where would you store those passwords for document? In database? Is it secure? thanks

Comment: You can definetly send those password by email. Why it does not make secure. Many product work as it is. You have to choose whether it will be a single use password(token) or a permanent password for the pdf for each user (even one password for the pdf without regard to users)